# How to create Spring Rest WebService that consumes payloads of xml without creating Entity / Custom Objects

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services

I want to create a rest web service method to consume an xml object without creating a custom object like Person.class.

heres my code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(
        value="/person", method=RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML} )
public Object person( @RequestBody Object object ){
        // some codes here
        return object;
}
```

payloads:

```
<Person>
<name>Coffee</name>
<age>25</age>
</Person>
```

How to make the method consumes the payloads of xml without creating Person class.

Please help me thnx

Comment: If you don't want to write a `Person` Class, how do you want to get `Person` information? String, JSON, ...? This will be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to implement a Person class?

Comment: i just want to create a method that is dynamically consumes xml data presentation. example is xml of <Person></Person> another is <Student></Student>. that is don't need to create the following class of Person and student.